# SharedPreferences for save the value of TextView?

Tags: java, android, xml

i've a ViewPager with three fragments. In the first fragment i have a Button, If you press shows two TextView with a different text. If I go to the third fragment and then I go back to the first, do not I see more TextView. I understand that you have to use SharedPreferences to not lose the value, then I made this code, but it does not work.

```
    TextView1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
    TextView2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2; 



    Button b1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             // CODE HERE

            SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
                      "com.MyPackage.AppName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);                 
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
              editor.putString("TextView1",TextView1.getText().toString());
              editor.putString("TextView2",TextView2.getText().toString());
              editor.commit();
```

}
        );

Why does not it work? If when I close the application I want to delete the values ​​stored in SharedPreferences how can I do?

Comment: For the first question, try to import import android.preference.PreferenceManager and use SharedPreferences prefs =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

Comment: @Simone please see my answer, it should help you out

Comment: @Simone Piglietti please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

The code fragment you currently give is correct. I think that probably you miss some code to actually restore the stored values (get from the preferences by key and use `setText`), or do not call it at the right time.

Try to put such code into the overridden `onResume` method of your activity.

It is unusual to store the state in response to pressing the button. Read more here about activity life cycle and [which methods are automatically called](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) for you at the certain times.

Answer (score 0):

To write to a SharedPref you can use this code:

```
String text = "Your text here";    
Context context = getApplicationContext();
AppPrefs appPrefs = new AppPrefs(context);
appPrefs.setSessionId(text);
```

To read from a SharedPref you can use this:

```
String textViewTextHolder = appPrefs.getSessionId();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using **static variables**  for what you want to do:

Example of static variables:

```
public static int i = 1;
```

To access this in another activity:

```
if(MainActivity.i == 1){
}
```

if you want to stick with shared preferences for any reason, you could clear them on the app **launch**, although I would advise not using shared preferences for what you are doing.

Comment: You'd advise using public fields that can be accessed by any class?

Comment: @DHT yes, for something like this, that is what I would do. Then fragments could communicate with each other through those variables, and you don't have to changing your shared preferences